# Custom ListView filtering on attributes from menu

Tags: android, listview, filter, attributes, menuitem

I have successfully implemented a custom sticky list adapter to display a list of products read from a database and sorted by price.
Now I want to implement `getFilter()` based on product attributes. For example, `where type = lipstick` which maintains the original sort by price.
Filter parameters are selected from menu.
All of the filtering examples are based on CharSequence input.
Would appreciate your help.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemID = item.getItemId();
    switch (itemID){
        case R.id.barEye:{
            dispatchFilterIntent(ACTION_FILTER_EYE);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.barLip:{
            dispatchFilterIntent(ACTION_FILTER_LIP);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.barNail:{
            dispatchFilterIntent(ACTION_FILTER_NAIL);
            break;
        }
  }
```

}